# Why does "The Wolf Among Us" Download on Steam not finish?

Tags: steam, the-wolf-among-us

On 3.1/3.9gb my download for *The Wolf Among Us* stops and throws a steam error, leading to  [this page](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8676-EFLX-7453&l=german). I tried everything on there. Still having the same issue!

Can anyone help out?

Comment: Happened to me too while downloading different game. Maybe Steam is overloaded because of the Summer sale. Try deleting local data for the game and download again.

Answer (score -1):

Try the official workaround. Close Steam, delete the "appcache" folder in your Steam install-directory and restart your computer... Worked for me after I was posting here about having the same problem, hope it helps you!